# app script that is pulling back all rows of data instead of the accurate filtered data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

the below code is from app scripts linked to a Google sheet - the code dynamically updates the number of filters based on columns.  If more columns are added, more filters are dynamically added.  This works well.  However, when you click the down arrow to select an item, it returns every row in the sheet instead of the row that matches the filter.  Modified this post added a screenshot of the google sheet and the output from the call, and added the HTML code. Please help:

[Screenshot of Googlesheet that has data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YJAE.png)

[Screenshot showing all rows returned instead of matching row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG3TE.png)

```
const SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pjuo4NbXrllidpn2QkzsuWWvPvoKNq79uXrV1hrQDh4/edit#gid=0';

/**
 * Main function to serve HTML for Web App.
 * @param {Object} e - Event parameter that can contain information about any URL parameters provided.
 * @returns {HtmlOutput} - A prepared HTML page ready for user interaction.
 */
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebApp');
}

/**
 * Opens the main spreadsheet and returns the specified sheet.
 * @param {string} sheetName - The name of the sheet to retrieve.
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} - The specified sheet.
 */
function getSheetByName(sheetName) {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    return ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the headers from "Sheet1" of the Google Spreadsheet.
 * @returns {Array} - An array of headers.
 */
function getHeaders() {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    return webAppSheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, webAppSheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}

/**
 * Retrieves unique values for each column from "Sheet1" of the Google Spreadsheet.
 * @returns {Object} - An object containing unique values for each header.
 */
function getColumnUniqueValues() {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let lastColumn = webAppSheet1.getLastColumn();
    let lastRow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
    let values = webAppSheet1.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn).getValues();

    let uniqueValues = {};
    getHeaders().forEach((header, index) => {
        uniqueValues[header] = [...new Set(values.map(row => row[index]))];
    });

    return uniqueValues;
}

/**
 * Retrieves filtered results based on the provided filters.
 * @param {Object} filters - An object containing column header-value pairs for filtering.
 * @returns {Array} - An array containing rows of data that match the filter criteria.
 */
function getResultsSQL(filters) {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let webAppSheet2 = getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let headers = getHeaders();
    let data = webAppSheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

    let matchingRows = data.filter((row, rowIndex) => {
        if (rowIndex === 0) return false;  // skip header row
        return headers.every((header, colIndex) => {
            let filterValue = filters[header];
            if (!filterValue || filterValue.trim() === '') {
                // If there's no filter value, don't filter out this row for this column
                return true;
            }
            // If there's a filter value, only keep this row if the value matches
            return row[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase() === filterValue.toLowerCase();
        });
    });

    webAppSheet2.clearContents();
    if (matchingRows.length) {
        webAppSheet2.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
        webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, matchingRows.length, headers.length).setValues(matchingRows);
    }

    return matchingRows.length ? [headers].concat(matchingRows) : [headers];
}
```

> 

Drop down filter should return the row that matches the filter.

```js
const SPREADSHEET_URL = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pjuo4NbXrllidpn2QkzsuWWvPvoKNq79uXrV1hrQDh4/edit#gid=0';

/**
 * Main function to serve HTML for Web App.
 * @param {Object} e - Event parameter that can contain information about any URL parameters provided.
 * @returns {HtmlOutput} - A prepared HTML page ready for user interaction.
 */
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebApp');
}

/**
 * Opens the main spreadsheet and returns the specified sheet.
 * @param {string} sheetName - The name of the sheet to retrieve.
 * @returns {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} - The specified sheet.
 */
function getSheetByName(sheetName) {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    return ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the headers from "Sheet1" of the Google Spreadsheet.
 * @returns {Array} - An array of headers.
 */
function getHeaders() {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    return webAppSheet1.getRange(1, 1, 1, webAppSheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
}

/**
 * Retrieves unique values for each column from "Sheet1" of the Google Spreadsheet.
 * @returns {Object} - An object containing unique values for each header.
 */
function getColumnUniqueValues() {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let lastColumn = webAppSheet1.getLastColumn();
    let lastRow = webAppSheet1.getLastRow();
    let values = webAppSheet1.getRange(2, 1, lastRow-1, lastColumn).getValues();

    let uniqueValues = {};
    getHeaders().forEach((header, index) => {
        uniqueValues[header] = [...new Set(values.map(row => row[index]))];
    });

    return uniqueValues;
}

/**
 * Retrieves filtered results based on the provided filters.
 * @param {Object} filters - An object containing column header-value pairs for filtering.
 * @returns {Array} - An array containing rows of data that match the filter criteria.
 */
function getResultsSQL(filters) {
    let webAppSheet1 = getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let webAppSheet2 = getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    let headers = getHeaders();
    let data = webAppSheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

    let matchingRows = data.filter((row, rowIndex) => {
        if (rowIndex === 0) return false;  // skip header row
        return headers.every((header, colIndex) => {
            let filterValue = filters[header];
            if (!filterValue || filterValue.trim() === '') {
                // If there's no filter value, don't filter out this row for this column
                return true;
            }
            // If there's a filter value, only keep this row if the value matches
            return row[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase() === filterValue.toLowerCase();
        });
    });

    webAppSheet2.clearContents();
    if (matchingRows.length) {
        webAppSheet2.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
        webAppSheet2.getRange(2, 1, matchingRows.length, headers.length).setValues(matchingRows);
    }

    return matchingRows.length ? [headers].concat(matchingRows) : [headers];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            margin: 40px;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        div {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        input[type="text"], input[type="button"], select {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        input[type="button"] {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #007BFF;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
        }

        input[type="button"]:hover {
            background-color: #0056b3;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        tr:hover {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
       function loadHeadersAndDropdowns() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayFilters).getHeaders();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillDatalists).getColumnUniqueValues();
        }

        function displayFilters(headers) {
            var filtersDiv = document.getElementById("filters");
            headers.forEach(function(header) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                var label = document.createElement("label");
                label.innerHTML = header + ":";
                label.setAttribute("for", header);

                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("list", header + "List");
                input.setAttribute("id", header);
                input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter " + header);

                var datalist = document.createElement("datalist");
                datalist.setAttribute("id", header + "List");

                div.appendChild(label);
                div.appendChild(input);
                div.appendChild(datalist);

                filtersDiv.appendChild(div);
            });
        }

        function fillDatalists(uniqueValues) {
            for (let header in uniqueValues) {
                let datalist = document.getElementById(header + "List");
                if (datalist) {
                    uniqueValues[header].forEach(value => {
                        let option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = value;
                        datalist.appendChild(option);
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        function GetReport() {
            var filters = {};
            var selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");
            selects.forEach(function(selectElement) {
                filters[selectElement.id] = selectElement.value;
            });

            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
                var displayTable = '<table border="1" cellpadding="5px" >';
                ar.forEach(function(item, index) {   
                    if(index == 0) {
                        displayTable += "<tr>";
                        item.forEach(function(header) {
                            displayTable += "<th>" + header + "</th>";
                        });
                        displayTable += "</tr>";          
                    } else {
                        displayTable += "<tr>";
                        item.forEach(function(cell) {
                            displayTable += "<td>" + cell + "</td>";
                        });
                        displayTable += "</tr>";    
                    }
                });

                displayTable += '</table>';
                document.getElementById("displayTableHere").innerHTML = displayTable;
            }).getResultsSQL(filters);
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadHeadersAndDropdowns()">
    <div id="filters"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="GetReport()" />
    </div>
    <div id="displayTableHere"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Stylesheet -->
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f3f3f3;
            margin: 40px;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }

        div {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        label {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        input[type="text"], input[type="button"], select {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        input[type="button"] {
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #007BFF;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
        }

        input[type="button"]:hover {
            background-color: #0056b3;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 8px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
        }

        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }

        tr:hover {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
     function loadHeadersAndDropdowns() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayFilters).getHeaders();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fillDatalists).getColumnUniqueValues();
}

function displayFilters(headers) {
    var filtersDiv = document.getElementById("filters");
    headers.forEach(function(header) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        label.innerHTML = header + ":";
        label.setAttribute("for", header);

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("list", header + "List");
        input.setAttribute("id", header);
        input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Enter " + header);

        var datalist = document.createElement("datalist");
        datalist.setAttribute("id", header + "List");

        div.appendChild(label);
        div.appendChild(input);
        div.appendChild(datalist);

        filtersDiv.appendChild(div);
    });
}

function fillDatalists(uniqueValues) {
    for (let header in uniqueValues) {
        let datalist = document.getElementById(header + "List");
        if (datalist) {
            uniqueValues[header].forEach(value => {
                let option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = value;
                datalist.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    }
}

function GetReport() {
    var filters = {};
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[list]");  // Get input elements associated with datalists
    inputs.forEach(function(inputElement) {
        filters[inputElement.id] = inputElement.value;
    });

    // Log the constructed filters for debugging
    console.log(filters);

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
        var displayTable = '<table border="1" cellpadding="5px" >';
        ar.forEach(function(item, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                displayTable += "<tr>";
                item.forEach(function(header) {
                    displayTable += "<th>" + header + "</th>";
                });
                displayTable += "</tr>";
            } else {
                displayTable += "<tr>";
                item.forEach(function(cell) {
                    displayTable += "<td>" + cell + "</td>";
                });
                displayTable += "</tr>";
            }
        });

        displayTable += '</table>';
        document.getElementById("displayTableHere").innerHTML = displayTable;
    }).getResultsSQL(filters);
}

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="loadHeadersAndDropdowns()">
    <div id="filters"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="GetReport()" />
    </div>
    <div id="displayTableHere"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I figured out the issue - here is the updated HTML code. I was using 'select' instead of 'input' - thank you for all that responded back. This is a cool script - feel free to use it - it will output to an HTML file no matter how many items you add to the sheet.

Comment: Try printing out the `filters` parameter and post what it says.

Comment: My guess is `filters[header]` is becoming `undefined`.

Comment: Unless you can provide us a way to reproduce your results then we probably will not be able to help you.  It's hard to trouble shoot a problem that doesn't exist for us. I don't know about others but I never use the filter functions built into the spreadsheet.  I prefer to do it in software.

Comment: Cooper - I get it, I like software too.  But working on something for a client, and my options are limited.  I only have Google Forms and Google sheets to do some automation functionality.

Comment: -TheMaster - I gave both sets of code to reproduce it.

Comment: ProblemsLoop - here is the log: Sep 24, 2023, 11:45:32 AM Info Filters used:
Sep 24, 2023, 11:45:32 AM Info {}

Comment: @all - fixed it - there was an issue in my HTML code. - Thank you ProblemsLoop, TheMaster, and Cooper!